# Spring reactive security: what do ServerAuthenticationConverter and ReactiveAuthenticationManager stand for

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I don't quite figure out what are `ServerAuthenticationConverter` and `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`:

`ServerAuthenticationConverter` Spring boot code is:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ServerAuthenticationConverter {

    /**
     * Converts a {@link ServerWebExchange} to an {@link Authentication}
     * @param exchange The {@link ServerWebExchange}
     * @return A {@link Mono} representing an {@link Authentication}
     */
    Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange);

}
```

and `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    /**
     * Attempts to authenticate the provided {@link Authentication}
     * @param authentication the {@link Authentication} to test
     * @return if authentication is successful an {@link Authentication} is returned. If
     * authentication cannot be determined, an empty Mono is returned. If authentication
     * fails, a Mono error is returned.
     */
    Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication);

}
```

Both have a method that returns a `Mono<Authentication>`:

What do they stand for?

Currently, My implementations are:

```java
@Component
public class GitJwtServerAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange)
            .flatMap((it) -> Mono.justOrEmpty(it.getRequest().getHeaders()))
            .map((headers) -> headers.get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
            .map((header) -> new GitBearerTokenAuthenticationToken(header.get(0)));
    }

}
```

and really straightforwardly implementation:

```java
public class GitJwtReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(authentication);
    }
    
}
```

My security implementation is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
        return new GitJwtReactiveAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter(
        ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager,
        ServerAuthenticationConverter serverAuthenticationConverter
    ) {
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(reactiveAuthenticationManager);
        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(serverAuthenticationConverter);

        return authenticationWebFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http,
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter
    ) {
        return http
            .httpBasic(HttpBasicSpec::disable)
            .csrf(CsrfSpec::disable)
            .formLogin(FormLoginSpec::disable)
            .anonymous(AnonymousSpec::disable)
            .logout(LogoutSpec::disable)
            .authorizeExchange((authorize) -> authorize
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            // .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()))
            .build();
    }

}
```

I've tested it, and I'm getting an `403 forbidden`:

```
~ ❯ curl -i -X POST localhost:8080/me -H "Authorization: $JWT_TOKEN" -H "GICAR_ID: foo"
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
content-length: 13

Access Denied%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### ServerAuthenticationConverter

> Converts a {@link ServerWebExchange} to an {@link Authentication}

The `ServerWebExchange` is what contains your request/response. Its the exchange between the client and the server. You have for instance to the `ServerWebExchange` in a `WebFilter`.

And as the doccumentation states, you can convert (most likely) a `ServerRequest` into an [`Authentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object.

And `Authentication` object represents either something that is going to be authenticated, or something that has been authenticated.

You for instance pass an authentication object to `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication)` where you can implement your own `AuthenticationManager`.

### ReactiveAuthenticationManager

Using this interface you implement your actual authentication. So this is where you for instance check that the username and password are correct. Or you check the signing and validity of your JWT.

This is where the most important nitty gritty is implemented and this is where you should have no bugs.

A typical flow would be

- Convert the request to an authentication object
- pass the authentication object to the authenticationmanager for authentication.
- the authenticationmanager returns a fully authenticated object
- create the userdetails object and set it in the security context

All this is documented in the spring security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html

also there is already a jwt implementation in spring security

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html